# token (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 210 for <USER>) can't be found in cache

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, hadoop-yarn

I´m using Kerberized hadoop cluster (Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.4) with Spark 1.3 and YARN. I´ve been trying for hours to find out the origin of this error produced by scala 2.10 application:

```
16/04/16 10:32:33 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): token (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 210 for XXXXXX) can't be found in cache
16/04/16 10:32:33 WARN hdfs.LeaseRenewer: Failed to renew lease for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_462399399_14] for 30 seconds.  Will retry shortly ...
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): token (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 210 for XXXXXX) can't be found in cache
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
```

I reproduce the code using pyspark and got the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the entires in the web were related with configuration issues that didnt worked for me.

Finally I found out that it was caused by a programming decission. The code was creating and stoping several spark contexts, secuencially not concurrently. After removing this multiple creation and using a single spark context, the errors disapeared and the app finished without issues.

Hope this helps to someone.